# GNU Sed format USA address to Street, City, State, Zip

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following data for some of my customers:

```
719 13th Street East, Glencoe MN, 55336
626 Valley Road, Montclair NJ, 07043
666 EAST DYER ROAD, SANTA ANA CA, 92705
20800 N. 135th Ave, Sun City West AZ, 85375
9775 Herring Gull Drive, Indianapolis IN, 46280
712 21st Street, Vero Beach FL, 32960
PO BOX 324, PORT SALERNO FL, 34992
207 Middleton Road, Lafayette LA, 70503
5091 nw fiddle leaf ct, port saint lucie FL, 34986
347 Mayberry Lane, Dover DE, 19904
2648 SW 137th Ave, Miramar FL, 33027
4410 Williams Dr SUITE 104, Georgetown TX, 78628
17020 Windsor Court, Homer Glen IL, 60491
11 Technology Drive North, Warren NJ, 07059
655 Boylston St, Boston MA, 02116
1375 bishops terrace, wixom MI, 48393
4705 Center Blvd Apt. 808, Long Island City NY, 11109
5340 CORNELIA HWY, ALTO GA, 30510
1541 Paces Ferry North, Smyrna GA, 30080
603 west pacific coast hwy, wilmington CA, 90744
2503Paddock CT, Louisville KY, 40216
9421 Dunbar dr, Oakland CA, 94603
1804 Third Avenue Apt #8, New York NY, 10029
2504  bellaire  st, wantagh NY, 11793
1380 avon lane apt 21, north lauderdale  FL, 33068
```

How can I use SED regex to format it like
Street Address|City|State|Zip

eg.

```
719 13th Street East|Glencoe|MN|55336
626 Valley Road|Montclair|NJ|07043
666 EAST DYER ROAD|SANTA ANA|CA|92705
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
sed -e 's/\([A-Z]*\) \([A-Z][A-Z]\),/\1\|\2,/g' -e 's/, /\|/g'
```

it gets all `,` and subtitutes to `|`. Prior to that, searches for `AAAA AA,` and changes it to `AAAA|AA,` for the `City|State` part.

**Test**

```
$ sed -e 's/\([A-Z]*\) \([A-Z][A-Z]\),/\1\|\2,/g' -e 's/, /\|/g' your_file
719 13th Street East|Glencoe|MN|55336
626 Valley Road|Montclair|NJ|07043
666 EAST DYER ROAD|SANTA ANA|CA|92705
20800 N. 135th Ave|Sun City West|AZ|85375
9775 Herring Gull Drive|Indianapolis|IN|46280
712 21st Street|Vero Beach|FL|32960
PO BOX 324|PORT SALERNO|FL|34992
207 Middleton Road|Lafayette|LA|70503
5091 nw fiddle leaf ct|port saint lucie|FL|34986
347 Mayberry Lane|Dover|DE|19904
2648 SW 137th Ave|Miramar|FL|33027
4410 Williams Dr SUITE 104|Georgetown|TX|78628
17020 Windsor Court|Homer Glen|IL|60491
11 Technology Drive North|Warren|NJ|07059
```

Comment: Your answer is nice too! and I like this more +1!!

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 's/^\(.*\), *\(.*\) \(..\), \([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1|\2|\3|\4/'
```

or:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*), *(.*) (..), ([0-9]{5})/\1|\2|\3|\4/'
```

Output:

```
719 13th Street East|Glencoe|MN|55336
626 Valley Road|Montclair|NJ|07043
666 EAST DYER ROAD|SANTA ANA|CA|92705
20800 N. 135th Ave|Sun City West|AZ|85375
9775 Herring Gull Drive|Indianapolis|IN|46280
712 21st Street|Vero Beach|FL|32960
PO BOX 324|PORT SALERNO|FL|34992
207 Middleton Road|Lafayette|LA|70503
5091 nw fiddle leaf ct|port saint lucie|FL|34986
347 Mayberry Lane|Dover|DE|19904
2648 SW 137th Ave|Miramar|FL|33027
4410 Williams Dr SUITE 104|Georgetown|TX|78628
17020 Windsor Court|Homer Glen|IL|60491
11 Technology Drive North|Warren|NJ|07059
655 Boylston St|Boston|MA|02116
1375 bishops terrace|wixom|MI|48393
4705 Center Blvd Apt. 808|Long Island City|NY|11109
5340 CORNELIA HWY|ALTO|GA|30510
1541 Paces Ferry North|Smyrna|GA|30080
603 west pacific coast hwy|wilmington|CA|90744
2503Paddock CT|Louisville|KY|40216
9421 Dunbar dr|Oakland|CA|94603
1804 Third Avenue Apt #8|New York|NY|10029
2504  bellaire  st|wantagh|NY|11793
1380 avon lane apt 21|north lauderdale |FL|33068
```

Comment: Good way also, like it. You can change `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` for `[0-9]*`.

Comment: @fedorqui Don't want to match other than 5 digits in zip code. But I changed to `sed -r` and can use `{5}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed -e 's/, /|/g' -e 's/ \([^ ]\+\)$/|\1/' file
```

Comment: state does not appear in separate field

Comment: may be u r suspecting too much :) +

Comment: Just for clarity - I suspect ... it doesn't work on MAC bash :)